# Lucene: Query at least

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to find if there's a way to search in lucene to say find all documents where there is at least one word that does not match a particualar word.

E.g. I want to find all documents where there is at least one word besides "test". i.e. "test" may or may not be present but there should be at least one word other than "test". Is there a way to do this in Lucene?

thanks,
Purushotham

Answer (score 0):

Lucene could do this, but this wouldn't be a good idea.

The performance of query execution is bound to two factors:

1. the time to intersect the query with the term dictionary,
2. the time to retrieve the docs for every matching term.

Performant queries are the ones which can be quickly intersected with the term dictionary, and match only a few terms so that the second step doesn't take too long. For example, in order to prohibit too complex boolean queries, Lucene limits the number of clauses to 1024 by default.

With a TermQuery, intersecting the term dictionary requires (by default) `O(log(n))` operations (where n is the size of the term dictionary) in memory and then one random access on disk plus the streaming of at most 16 terms. Another example is this [blog entry from Lucene committer Mike McCandless](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html) which describes how FuzzyQuery performance improved when a brute-force implementation of the first step was replaced by something more clever.

However, the query you are describing would require to examine every single term of the term dictionary and dismiss documents which are in the "test" document set only!

You should give more details about your use-case so that people can think about a more efficient solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a query with a single negative condition, then use a BooleanQuery with the MatchAllDocsQuery and a TermQuery with occurs=MUST_NOT. There is no way to additionaly enforce the existential constraint ("must contain at least one term that is not excluded"). You'll have to check that separately, once you retrieve Lucene's results. Depending on the ratio of favorable results to all the results returned from Lucene, this kind of solution can range from perfectly fine to a performance disaster.